# Does overloaded version of Task.WaitAny Cancel the task?

Tags: c#, multithreading

```
int WaitAny(Task[] tasks, int millisecondsTimeout);
```

Does the above method cancel the task after the timeout period? It looks it doesn't but C# 70-483 exam reference book says this overloaded version cancel the task. Here is some test code,

```
Task longRunning = Task.Run(() =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
});
int index = Task.WaitAny(new Task[] { longRunning }, 1000); // returns -1
index = 0; // reset it to reuse in the loop
while (index < 12)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    index++;
    Console.WriteLine("long running task status {0}", longRunning.Status);
}
```

First few times, Status is Running and after that the status change to RanToCompletion. So what that time out does related to Task and WaitAny?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "first few times"? After the 10 seconds has elapsed, the long-running task *will* have run to completion... Can you quote the *exact* statement in the exam reference book?

Comment: After 1000 milliseconds it will stop waiting. Thats the time out for waiting. Just like other wait methods.

Comment: @JonSkeet  I am talking about task status while the while loop is running. Because the current thread is blocking and in the mean time the longRunning task also doing its job. in the loop first 8 times (few times) print ths status as Running  and after that  loop print the status as RanToCompletion.

Comment: Right, and why is that surprising? The task *isn't* cancelled... it runs to completion. That's why I asked you to quote the *exact* statement that claims it's canceled by WaitAny.

Comment: It surprises me because the book "Exam Ref 70-483" says on page 39 "If you want to cancel a Task after a certain amount of time, you can use an overload of Task.WaitAny that takes a timeout". I verify  this statement with you all experts. Looks the book misleads. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`Task.WaitAny` will complete if either (a) any of tasks it wraps complete or (b) the timeout is exceeded. If the timeout is exceeded, `WaitAny` completes, but the tasks it wraps will not be cancelled. Cancellation with tasks tends to be cooperative rather than implicit, and will involve the ***explicit*** passing of a `CancellationToken`.

If you want the task to cancel after a timeout you can create a `CancellationTokenSource` with a timeout and pass that into the task you're waiting for:

```
 using(CancellationTokenSource cts=new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)))
{
    var task = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), cts.Token);
    task.Wait();
}
```

Of course, waiting for tasks to complete using blocking methods is **highly** discouraged, as is wrapping synchronous blocking code in `Task.Run` and expecting everything to work correctly and "asynchronously".

[Embrace async/await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) for the win.

Answer (score 0):

If you look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235650(v=vs.110).aspx
IT says waitAny returns -1 if timeout has occurred. which is the result you are getting in the first place. Isn't that your expectation?

This means the code continues past WaitAny but does not mean that the tasks it was waiting for have been cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

> So what that time out does related to Task and WaitAny?

It does nothing. When you set time-out of 10000 it's like if you say:

"*Hey Task, i give you ten seconds to finish, but then i'll keep going regardless of what's going on...*"